Instasharper: Unable to upload photo: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0
I am using a private Instagram API for C# known as InstaSharper, I built my code like the Documentation found on its GitHub but no matter what I do I keep getting the same Error when trying to Upload a Picture. My Code is as Followed:
`
private static IInstaApi _instaApi;
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // Define user credentials
    var userCredentials = new UserSessionData
    {
        UserName = "MyInstagramUsername",
        Password = "MyInstagramPassword"
    };

    _instaApi = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
        .SetUser(userCredentials)
        .UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.All))
        .Build();

    var loginResult = await _instaApi.LoginAsync();

    if (loginResult.Succeeded)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Logged in successfully.");
        await InsertImage(@"C:\Insta\testImage.png");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to log in: {loginResult.Info.Message}");
    }
}

public static async Task InsertImage(string _path)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(_path), UriKind.Absolute).LocalPath);   
    var mediaImage = new InstaImage
    {
        URI = new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(_path), UriKind.Absolute).LocalPath,
        Width = 1080,
        Height = 1080
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Media Made");
    var result = await _instaApi.UploadPhotoAsync(mediaImage, "Caption");

    if (result.Succeeded == true) Console.WriteLine($"Media created: {result.Value.Pk}, {    result.Value.Caption}");
    else Console.WriteLine($"Unable to upload photo: {result.Info.Message}");
    Console.WriteLine("End of Function");
}

`
and the Error Unable to upload photo: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. keeps happening on the var result = await _instaApi.UploadPhotoAsync(mediaImage, "Caption");
I've tried everything I was able to find in the Offical Documentation.
Update:
It was suggested by @dbc that I log everything ToString in the Console, which showed that I was receiving an HTML Document instead of the Expected JSON.
<html lang="None" class="no-js not-logged-in ">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> Page Not Found &bull; Instagram </title>

    <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/data/manifest.json">
</head>

However I have not Managed to fix it.

maybe can try this sample UploadPhoto. use InstaImageUpload instead InstaImage.

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: < often means that HTML or XML was encountered when JSON was expected.  Do you have the full ToString() output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?  If so, might you please [edit] your question to include it?

@dbc I have updated it but still have no fix

Look at the whole response - as @dbc hints at, it's probably an error page in HTML that might explain what the issue is.
